React onClick Events on Stencil Generated Buttons Inside Parent Stencil Component
I created a custom button on StencilJS and I am using on a React app.
I can assign an method to the onClick attr of my custom button and it works fine.
There is a problem however when I use my custom button inside another StencilJS component.
NOTE: The handleClick method is in my React component!
UPDATE: using other React events like onDoubleClick, onMouseEnter, etc... the handleClick method in the React component executes just fine.  Why is it that onClick is not working for me within my Stencil component?
UPDATE 2: I use onClick within the code for my Stencil component and within the same there is a method.
I ripped every single one of the onClicks inside my Stencil component and now the onClick on the React component works again!
Well it turns out that if I use onClick events within my Stencil component then that causes the onClick used in the React component to be completely useless.
Example:
// my method
const handleClick = () => {
  console.log('Custom button clicked!')
}

// works with
<StencilButton label="Click Me!" onClick={handleClick) />

// click on button inside another Stencil component does not execute the handleClick method
<ParentStencilComponent>
    <StencilButton label="Click Child Button!" onClick={handleClick) />
</ParentStencilComponent>

Even if I place a plain button with an onClick inside my StencilJS component the click doesn't work!
<button onClick={handleClick}>Click Me Too!</button>

Is there something I am missing that I need to enable in the Stencil code for my CustomButton?

UPDATE and FIXED!   So I discovered that there was a e.stopPropagation in my StencilJS component that basically prevented any other onClick inside of it from firing. C'est la vie!
